# Redefining title with functionality in a style file

Tags: titles

I am changing the layout of the title page by redefining `\@maketitle`.

How can I do the same in `expl3` ?  If I want to have the capability of having a number of page layouts for users to call, would it still be a sensible idea to redefine `\@maketitle`, or should I do something else ?

```
\ProvidesPackage{piton}[2023/08/13]

\ExplSyntaxOn  

\def \@maketitle
  {
    \newpage
    \null
    \vskip 2em

    \begin{center}
      \let \footnote \thanks
        { \LARGE \@title \par }
        \vskip 1.5em
        {
          \large
          \lineskip .5em%
          \begin{tabular}[t]{c}
            \@author
          \end{tabular}\par
        }
      % \vskip 1em
      % {\large \@date}
    \end{center}

    \par
    \vskip 1.5em
}

\ExplSyntaxOff 


\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage {piton}

\title{A Minimal Working Example}
\author{Likku Cirillu}
\date{2023/08/13}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Something Something

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you wonder why some people are giving a thumbs down: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that and please explain your question better, it is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Because I intend to use `expl3` commands rather than those shown.  Asking what changes I would have to do.

Comment: So is your question "Here's what I've done so far, how do I do this in `expl3`?"  Or is your question "I'm creating a style file, how do I give my users options for styling the title?"  Or do you have another question entirely?

Comment: Yes, it is how to do this in `expl3`. And whether it is a good idea to redefine `\@maketitle` every time users change the title page options.  Or whether I should leave `\@maketitle` alone and not mess with the its class definition,

Comment: Based on all of your questions, you appear to have some idea of a project, but you're not really sharing enough information for us to help you.  If you're aiming to have `\titleformat{optionN}` where `N` is one of 5 different options, then it won't be customizable enough to suit someone.  By the time you increase `N` to suit everyone, they would be better off just styling the title themself.  I would recommend that your package create at most one way to style the title page.

Comment: You are quite right.  Would be better for users to make their own.  I need some clarification on what circumstances should one change `\@maketitle` or use `\begin{titlepage}`.